# How to pay for an app in Software Center

Tags: 11.10, software-center, ubuntu-pay

I have seen several apps that cost an amount in Software Center to adquire them. So I have some questions:

1. How does one pay for this apps?
2. What currency is supported?
3. What methods of payments are supported?
4. How does the system know I am the one that paid for a app if I format the PC. Is there a way to store the app I bought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pay for the app, it's handled through your Ubuntu Single Sign-on account. You have a username and password (which can be the same as Launchpad).

I don't know what payment options are available, since I've only downloaded free apps that use that system. Upon payment, you get what amounts to a special PPA with the program.

There's a menu item that will let you restore previously-purchased items. I think it just adds the PPA and installs the package.